# How to check the element titled AA E-mail Address is enabled or not

Tags: selenium, dynamics-crm-2013

Hi I have the following html,

```
<td class="ms-crm-ReadField-Normal ms-crm-FieldLabel-RightAlign" id="agf_accountaccessemailaddressverified_c" title="AA E-mail Address Verified?">
    <span class="ms-crm-InlineEditLabel">
        <span class="ms-crm-InlineEditLabelText" style="max-width:200px;text-align:Right;width:80%;">
            AA E-mail Address Verified?
        </span>
        <div class="ms-crm-Inline-GradientMask" style="display: none;">
        </div>
    </span>
</td>
```

I would like to see whether the checkbox AA E-mail Address Verified? as enabled or not using selenium webdriver.

I tried the following method :

```
bool check = driverIE.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#agf_accountaccessemailaddressverified_c > span:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)")).Enabled;
```

or

```
bool check = driverIE.FindElement(By.Id("agf_accountaccessemailaddressverified_c")).Enabled;
```

Still getting the error that unable to find element.

Any help much appreciated?

Comment: that is a span right it won't have enabled or diabled property

Comment: In UI, its a check box. so I want to test whether its enabled or not

Comment: have you tried `driverIE.FindElement(By...).Selected`? Let me know if that works and I'll put it as an answer. The element is `Enabled`, because you can use it, what you're looking for is `Selected` I believe. Although your error leads me to believe your selector isn't finding the right element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Selenium, but a pure DOM way to find out if a field is locked would be through its lock icon.

For your field `agf_accountaccessemailaddressverified` there is a lock icon `span` tag with the id `agf_accountaccessemailaddressverified_lock`.

When locked it has the style `display: block;`,
When unlocked, it has the style `display: none;`

If you can check that with Selenium you should be able to test it properly.

The corresponding `input` doesn't get disabled, it just stays hidden in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with usage of it, but if Selenium behaves similarly to Chrome's F12 console, this will return the bool you need:

`frames[0].Xrm.Page.getControl("agf_accountaccessemailaddressverified").getDisabled();`

What I mean is, if you open the record in CRM, hit F12 and paste that in the console, it would return true or false depending on if the field is disabled or not. If Selenium runs javascript as it seems, it should not be that different.